# Python Help For Questions

Tags: python

I would like some help with a question on Python. Does anyone know why the coding language is so complicated to learn for some people? I need an answer in 1 week from now.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask those people

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion it isnt really that hard. Although, I do forget things here and there. I’d suggest using 3.6 if you are a beginner. Its where I started. If you need a sample program(s), you may use the following.

Printing to console:

```py
print(‘hello’)
```

Printing to console using variables:

```py
thisIsAString = ‘hello’
print(thisIsAString)
```

Here are some conditions.

```py
TrueBoolean = True
TrueString = ‘Yes’
TrueInt = 1
TrueList = [‘Yes’, 1, True]
if TrueBoolean: 
    print(‘Boolean is True’)
if TrueString == ‘Yes’:
    print(‘String is “Yes”’)
if TrueInt == 1:
    print(‘Int is “Yes”’)
if TrueList == [‘Yes’, 1, True]: # TrueList.contains(INSERT ITEMS HERE) works too.
    print(‘List is true’)
```

Comment: old me decided to put this as an answer instead of a comment ;-;